# Merge Overlapping Intervals Produces AttributeError

Tags: python, merge

> Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.
>
> For example:
>
> Given `[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]`,
>
> return `[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]`.
>
> Make sure the returned intervals are sorted.

```
class Solution:
    # @param intervals, a list of Intervals
    # @return a list of Interval
    def merge(self, intervals):
        A = intervals
        A.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
        N = len(A)
        S = []
        if A:
            S.append(A[0])
            for i in range(1, N):
                B = A[i]
                if B.start <= S[-1].end:
                    S[-1].end = max(S[-1].end, B.end)
                else:
                    S.append(B)
        return S

X=[[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
sol=Solution()
print(sol.merge(X))
```

After compiling I get an error:

```
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(sol.merge(X))
  File "main.py", line 8, in merge
    A.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
  File "main.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    A.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'
```

But the solution is accepted by **Interviewbit**.

Comment: The comment says "@param intervals, a list of Intervals", but you are sending a list of lists.

Comment: Well, you are passing in lists, and a list doesn't have a `.start` attribute. Have you read the problem description on Interviewbit properly? Perhaps they are passing in **something different** to represent intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a minimal `Interval` class to get your code running correctly:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start, self.end = start, end
    def __repr__(self):
        return str([self.start, self.end])
```

Or you can obtain roughly the same with `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Interval = namedtuple('Interval', ('start', 'end'))
```

And convert `X` to use `Interval`s:

```
X = [Interval(*x) for x in X]
```